# After GestureOverlayView has added a OnGesturePerformedListener, the gesture fade out automatically

Tags: android, gesture

After GestureOverlayView has added a GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener, the gesture I draw always fade out automatically,what should I do to avoid the fade out?

I found a method setFadeEnabled(boolean) in Android Develpers,but whatever I call it in onCreate() or onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture),the gesture I draw still fade out?
Please give me some ways，Thank You very much！

```
mOverlay = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gesture_layout);
    mOverlay.setFadeEnabled(false);
    mOverlay.addOnGesturePerformedListener(new OnGesturePerformedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mOverlay.setFadeEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has read the source code about the Gesture and GestureOverlayView.The Method setFadeEnabled(boolean) is only use to set fading out effect,not the whether fade out(disappear).
So there is not a method to solve my problem,only to modify the code source.

I am the newcomer in the the world of Android,there are my opinions,welcome to point out my faults.

Thx.